# How can I limit CD drive speed while on the live CD to avoid drive noise?

Tags: cd, drive

I sometimes disconect my harddisks for the weeks while only using the internet and I use the Ubuntu Live CD. But every time it needs something while in live desktop it accelerates and makes a lot of noise, also the acceleration takes too long. I want lower drive speed than acceleration lags, because acceleration lags stop me completly exactly when I need something.

How can I lower the CD drive speed, say to maximum 16x, without restarting?
I can't restart because I only use the CD drive, no harddisks, no flash disks, no network disks.

Edit:

No USB drives.

Setcd does not work for the live session.

Comment: why don't you use Ubuntu installed on pendrive?

Comment: i am not buying pen drives until they will get to 2$ for 4 GB...

Comment: also my bios does not support booting from USB because of seven year old computer with upgrades, not to the mainboard

Comment: You're using a CD. You don't need a 4GB drive to counter that. You can get a 1gig stick for £1. They're often faster than the CD too. And you can boot to USB via a floppy. I assume it has one of those if it won't boot USB. Edit: USB 1.1 is slightly slower than a 16x speed CD but it still has *much* faster seek times.

Comment: Ok, I am buying a USB drive and will use plop as my floppy drive has failed some years ago (it was a Sony). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, if you don't want to buy a pendrive, do the following lines:

```
sudo apt-get install setcd
setcd -x 1
```

Change `-x 1` to `-x [number]`. Higher the number, faster the drive.

But you should remember, that CD works on high speed for a reason. Ubuntu may become slow, when you do that.

Comment: I can optimise for best results: speed vs access time. From my experience 16x is the best optimisation.

Comment: setcd does not work for the live session - no effect not even with sudo setcd

Comment: well, it seems to have some effect... the cd stops faster from throttling :) thanks

Comment: @ Paweł Karpiński does not work with ASUS k50ij ubuntu 14.04 $ eject -x 1 works howerver, without anything to install, since `eject` is installed y default

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is use the supplied USB creator tool or Unetbootin to create a bootable USB drive, which is exactly the same thing as using a Live CD, only without the drive noise.

Comment: And the hardest thing to do if you do not have large USB drives. My biggest one is a PQI of 1GB but it has a USB 1.1 speed.